# Photography advice for creating building wraps

Tags: perspective, pano-projections

I'm looking for some advice for a project that I'm planning...

I'm going to be photographing the inside of a church for the purpose of creating a large banner to hide some restoration work taking place in a corner of the building.

The concept is to shoot images of the corner and then stitch these together for a 1-1 representation of that area. The client is going to print the image onto a banner and then hang the banner from a frame.

Simple so far...

My question is relating to the perspective which will be correct only from the point of view of the camera.

The height of the area is 15 meters. Ideally, I'd like to create the final image so that it doesn't distort towards the top of the image.

Any ideas on how to set up the camera to get as close to Orthographic projection as possible?

Comment: Easier to shoot and then correct with Lightroom perspective correction.

Comment: Might be worth hiring a tilt-shift if you haven't already!

Answer (score 1):

> The height of the area is 15 meters. Ideally, I'd like to create the final image so that it doesn't distort towards the top of the image.

Shoot from a platform that is about 7.5 meters high so that the camera can be pointed parallel to the ground and perpendicular to the face of the building.